# Hovering over a progress bar moves it slightly

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, progress-bar

I have created a progress bar using the following:

```
<progress value="20" max="100"></progress>
```

For the hover-text, I have used the following css:

```
progress[value] {
width: 1024px;
height: 20px;
border: none;
}
progress:hover::before {
display: block;
content: attr(value);
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

It can be seen here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aj4w9c3L/2/)

I know this only works in Google Chrome, but that is ok.

My issue is that when i hover my mouse over the progress bar, it moves a few pixels down. I have tried different border styles in the css, but without any luck. It shows the value correctly when i hover over the progress bar, but I would like for the progress bar to remain in place...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it `display:block` and the problem should disappear

```
progress[value] {

  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. I tried setting all kinds of stuff on the :hover::before because the behavior happened when i hovered. Setting it on the progress itself worked like a charm!